# How to create directory folder in specific location by input GUI pyqt4 python

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

Commonly I create directory using this code:

```
 directory = r'D:\myFolder'
 _dir=os.path.join(directory,'Result')
 if not os.path.exists(_dir):
        os.makedirs(_dir)
```

But, this time i want to make directory using GUI.
I get location to create directory :

```
  def get_dir():
       _dir= QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, 'Select a folder:', 'D:\\', QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
        return _dir
```

from `get_dir()` I get directory as string. And to create directory I should write `r'` before directory.... What should I do?

Comment: The `r` is only needed for string *literals* (so that backslashes aren't interpreted as escapes). The return value of `getExistingDirectory` is a `QString`, so you just need to convert that to a python string like this: `return unicode(_dir)`. But note that that is not sufficient on all platforms. On unix, it may also be necessary to encode the path using the filesystem encoding (depending on what you will be doing with the path afterwards).

Comment: Thank you @ekhumoro... it's work when I convert value of `getExistingDirectory` to python string. So, I don't need `r`   :)